# Response.Redirect() is appending the body of HTML to the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using `Response.Redirect` in ASP .NET C# application, to redirect to a different web page based on success or failure.
But Response.Redirect is not working. Instead or redirecting to the new link, the body or the contents of the target web page is appended to the existing URL. I tried it for a simple HelloWorld page and still its not working. For ex:

If I am in home page: `http://www.example.com/test/default.aspx`
and if I want to redirect to `HelloWord` html page, then the final URL would be
`Response.Redirect("~/../hello.html");` but I get `http://www.example.com/<p>Hello%20World!!</p>`

Due to the improper URL, I am getting "Access Denied Error".

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What is the root-url of your application ("/" or "/test")? What is the url you expect for that "hello.html" file? Can you access that hello.html file when you type in it's address in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
Response.Redirect("~/hello.html");
```

if your hello.html is in the application root directory.

Or if you want a relative parent directory to the current page:

```
Response.Redirect("../hello.html");
```

~ references the application root directory, so with "~/.." you are trying to access a parent of the root directory, that is not allowed.

Comment: Hello.html is present outside the application root folder. I have hosted the application under Default websites (root application folder in IIS) and I am having the HTML file under this folder. Since "~" would take me to the application root directory and I want access the file that is 1 more path up, I mentioned it "~/../". I do not think the problem is with path. If the problem is with path then I would get a message that web page is not available. But the content getting appended to the URL is little strange. Can the cookies be a problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Server.Transfer() instead. It will redirect you to a new page. For example:

> Server.Transfer("Home.html")

if the page is in the same directory, otherwise just use relative link

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect to a file that is outside of an IIS site, as "one level up from the app-root" probably is.

Answer (score -2):

Add the following code to the **Page_Load** event:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.microsoft.com");
```